# Enviar email com java

Tags: java, jpa

Boa tarde.
Estou usando java,JPA,wildfly e primefaces.
Precisoenviar um email de notificação depois que o usuario clicar no botão de enviar.Como devo proceder para enviar emails através do java?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor API para isso é a [JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/). Para utilizá-la você vai precisar de um provedor de emails (para o exemplo que cito seria um do gmail). Para exemplificar, o código de envio de email utilizando SSL ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public class SendMailSSL {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");
            }
        });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to@no-spam.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

É só um exemplo, mas pode variar dependendo da forma de autenticação e provedor de email utilizados. Dá uma olhada nesse [artigo](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/), que foi de onde tirei o exemplo acima usando SSL.

Comment: Giuliana testei e deu o seguinte erro: "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtT"......

Eu pesquisei sobre este erro e é detectado que devo ativar uma configuração do google para permissão, é como se fosse pra diminuir a segurança... realizei tal procedimento e mesmo assim continuou neste erro

Comment: Você criou o provedor de emails e ajustou o user e senha dele no exemplo acima em getPasswordAuthentication? Se sim, o erro não é trivial aí iria precisar da stacktrace completa para identificar o problema.

Comment: Estive viajando, por isso a demora, vamos lá consegui resolver o problema, configurei o getPasswordAuthentication e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Show! Marca como respondido pra ajudar outras pessoas :)